# Depthimage-to-laser issue with scan output

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using depthimage-to-laser. Running as simulation in gazebo with kinetic plug-in. I get the following error. Any thoughts on the nature of this error and if this is a parameter issue.

Would I be better off using: pointcloud-to-laserscan?

```
[ WARN] [1388168330.681229897, 962.989000000]: Laser has to be mounted planar! Z-coordinate has to be 1 or -1, but gave: 0.20080
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/113321/depthimage-to-laser-issue-with-scan-output/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2013-12-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am unfamiliar with this particular device but it sounds like "Laser has to be mounted planar" is telling you that you've managed to locate it in an "illegal" location.  It wants the scanner location somewhere in the z=1 or z=-1 plane and you've managed to simulate it elsewhere.  Any way you can adjust?

---

Originally posted by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) with karma: 429 on 2013-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2013-12-27**:
Thanks ... I had the wrong frame specified

**Comment by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on 2016-01-21**:
Where have you gone wrong in frame, how you fixed it, can you please elaborate.